# тег img и параметр max-height

Tags: html, css, img

Здравствуйте.

У меня имеется список фото, и ниже к ним описание. Все фото по ширине должны быть 200px жестко, поэтому у тега `img` параметр `width` проставлен `200`. Но сами фото по высоте разного размера. Поэтому описание у меня под фото идет лесенкой. Если я прописываю абсолютную длину, некоторые фото некрасиво растягиваются. Пытался сделать отдельный `div` с высотой, но тоже в итоге фото растягиваются.

А надо, чтобы к примеру чтобы фото размером 200х200 было такого размера, а фото 200х312 уменьшалось до 200х297, и у всех текст был ниже 297px

```
<div class="new">
<img src="../img/1733.jpg" width="200" height="297">
<br>описание
</div>
```

в css файле

```
new {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

можно втиснуть фото в другой контейнер и обрезать "лишнее".

```
<div class="new">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="some-class-for-img" src="../img/1733.jpg">
    </div>
    <br>описание
</div>

.img-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 297px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.some-class-for-img {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 297px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Второй вариант - сделать фото фоном для блока `img-wrapper` и назначить ему `background-size: contains`. Метод плох тем, что при печати страницы(Ctrl+P) все фотки пропадут

Comment: но тогда все фото больше 297, например 305 вылезут за границы

Comment: не вылезут. `overflow: hidden;` обрежет лишнее

Comment: но он получается обрежет, а как сделать так чтобы выше 297 не обрезало, а вписывало в 297

Comment: Тогда вы потеряете в ширине 200px. Изображение станет уже

Comment: это не критично для моего варианта

Comment: Тогда оставьте свой первоначальный вариант, но `width="200" height="297"` поменяйте на `max-width="200" max-height="297"`

Comment: но когда я пишу в теге img max-height="297" у меня фото, если оно больше 297px все равно больше чем 297

Comment: Перенесите это правило в `CSS`. Там наверняка сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Засунуть картинку в блок.
Если как фоновое изображение, то задать блоку свойство `background-size: contain;`
Если как `<img>`, то задать изображению свойство `Object-fit:scale-down` (большое изображение будет вписано в блок, маленькое - отцентрировано) или `Object-fit:contain` (большое вписано, маленькое - растянуто и вписано).